# Sorting/Filter posts from front-end in Wordpress blog

Tags: sort, filters

Here is the design I have mocked up 
http://enormo.us/clients/ischool/

The question is, how can I create a filtering system where the main blog area acts as the central feed and it combines the result of all three filters. I would know how to do one of those rows, but im having trouble with all three together.

For instance clicking on ischool life, students, and comments; would bring up only posts that are in the category iSchool Life, written by students, and sorted by the most comments.

Any help would be appreciated, even doing this type of thing not related to WordPress that would be cool too. I know it is used in eCommerce sites all the time.

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 3):

Best tutorial I've seen on doing this is Chris Coyier's Dynamic Archives on Digging into WordPress.

http://digwp.com/2010/10/dynamic-archives/